# Having trouble creating keystore file

Tags: android, keystore, keytool

I was following the and dev website's instructions for signing your app and I went into the cmd, went to the jdk folder and typed this in.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore mykey.keystore -alias coffee -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

After I put in a password and my name etc it gave me an error message that said

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mykey.keystore
```

I got the impression that the code I enterted would generate a keystore file as well as the key for my app. So what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without

```
-keystore mykey.keystore
```

so that it uses the default name ($HOME/.keystore).

Comment: keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mykey.keystore (Access is denied)

Comment: sorry - used wrong change.  instead of not using -v don't use -keystore.  See edited answer.

Comment: Ah, ok. Where should that file be stored?

Comment: Oh nvm I found it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you generate the keystore in eclipse for your project?

File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application

Should be self explanatory from there.

I'll keep looking up how to do it from command line and post if I see anything worthwhile!

But for further help with command line read this:

http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/